# How can I iterate through a DataFrame in the quickest way in terms of below example?

Tags: pandas, numpy, loops, filter, pandas-groupby

I am working on a project where I know store_code, product_code, a bigger product group "pmg" and a percentage per pmg which says how % of products the employees touch but right now I should know how many are these products accurately and put "1" next to them randomly.

My question is there is any quicker solution for calculating which product_code should get "1" than this below? because I have originally more than 480 000 rows and it takes 2h30m to iterate through df ("product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg ") and set "1" next to proper product? thank you for your help in advance

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import random 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def filter(df : pd.DataFrame, perc_to_cases_nr : pd.DataFrame):
    
    def tpn_lottery(tpn_list : list, count : int):
        return random.sample(tpn_list, count)


    selection = pd.Series(dtype = "int64")
    
    total_dict = product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg.to_dict('records')

    for row in tqdm(total_dict):
        
        df_part = df.loc[(df.store_code == row['store_code']) & (df.pmg == row['pmg'])]
        unique_tpns = set(df_part['product_code'])
        cases_nr = row["how_many_cases_we_need"]
        selected_tpn_list = tpn_lottery(unique_tpns, cases_nr)
        
        selection = pd.concat([selection, df_part['product_code'].isin(selected_tpn_list)])
    
    return  selection


# creating a df and another df (product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg ) which identifies where to need to put "1" in original df randomly

rand = np.random.randint(2**22, size=(2**16, 27))
a = [f"BWS0{i}"for i in range(1,10)]
b = [f"DRY0{i}"for i in range(1,10)]
c = [f"HEA0{i}"for i in range(1,10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(rand, columns = a+b+c ).melt(var_name = "pmg", value_name = "product_code").drop_duplicates()
df['store_code'] = 87001
product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg = df.copy()
product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg = product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg.groupby(['store_code',"pmg"]).agg(unique_product_no = ("product_code", 'nunique')).reset_index()
product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg['percentage_to_be_indicated'] = 0.15
product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg['how_many_cases_we_need'] = round(product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg['unique_product_no'] * product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg['percentage_to_be_indicated'],0).astype("int64")



df['Pre-sorted Cases'] = 0

df.loc[filter(df, product_numbers_we_need_per_pmg), "Pre-sorted Cases"] = 1
```